# Listening for events on a network and handling callbacks robostly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am developing a small Python program for the Raspberry Pi that listens for some events on a Zigbee network.

The way I've written this is rather simplisic, I have a while(True): loop checking for a Uniquie ID (UID) from the Zigbee. If a UID is received it's sent to a dictionary containing some callback methods. So, for instance, in the dictionary the key 101 is tied to a method called PrintHello().

So if that key/UID is received method PrintHello will be executed - pretty simple, like so:

```
if self.expectedCallBacks.has_key(UID) == True:
        self.expectedCallBacks[UID]()
```

I know this approach is probably too simplistic. My main concern is, what if the system is busy handling a method and the system receives another message?

On an embedded MCU I can handle easily with a circuler buffer + interrupts but I'm a bit lost with it comes to doing this with a RPi. Do I need to implement a new thread for the Zigbee module that basically fills a buffer that the call back handler can then retrieve/read from?

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to implement this more robustly.

Answer (score 0):

Threads can definitely help to some degree here. Here's a simple example using a `ThreadPool`:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(2)  # Create a 2-thread pool
while True:
   uid = zigbee.get_uid()
   if uid in self.expectedCallbacks:
       pool.apply_async(self.expectedCallbacks[UID])
```

That will kick off the callback in a thread in the thread pool, and should help prevent events from getting backed up before you can send them to a callback handler. The `ThreadPool` will internally handle queuing up any tasks that can't be run when all the threads in the pool are already doing work.

However, remember that Raspberry Pi's have only one CPU core, so you can't execute more than one CPU-based operation concurrently (and that's even ignoring the limitations of threading in Python caused by the [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-a-global-interpreter-lock-gil), which is normally solved by using [multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of threads). That means no matter how many threads/processes you have, only one can get access to the CPU at a time. For that reason, you probably don't want more than one thread actually running the callbacks, since as you add more you're just going to slow things down, due to the OS needing to constantly switch between threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had another thought that I wanted to run by, the modules sending messages to the RPi are actually MCUs and why not implement a simple acknowledgment system where if the MCU doesn't receive it simply sends the message 1 second or 5 seconds later.

Comment: @saad You could do that, it would just lead to a slightly more complicated implementation on both ends. Is it actually possible for the RPi to *miss* events sent to it with your current implementation? It's not clear to me what mechanism is actually being used to send the events over the network.